# LibGDX: How can I replace a SpriteBatch with another SpriteBatch?

Tags: android, libgdx

I want the splash2 to display the screen when score is 2. Right now the first splash is still showing and I don't know how to replace it with splash2 when score does.

```
public class Click1 implements Screen {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite splash;
private Sprite splash2;
private Sprite splash3;
private Sprite splash4;
private Sprite splash5;
private Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;
private Clickhud1 hud;
private float dt;
private static Integer score;

public Click1() {

}


public void update(float dt){

    handleInput(dt);
    hud.update(dt);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, camera);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    splash = new Sprite(new Texture("Clicks.png"));
    splash2 = new Sprite(new Texture("Clicks2.png"));
    splash3 = new Sprite(new Texture("Clicks3.png"));
    splash4 = new Sprite(new Texture("Clicks4.png"));
    splash5 = new Sprite(new Texture("Clicks5.png"));

    hud = new Clickhud1(Globals.game.batch);



}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);



 Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   if(score <= 1) {

        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(splash.getColor());
        batch.draw(
                splash,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
                splash.getRegionWidth(),
                splash.getRegionHeight());
        batch.end();


    }


   if(score <= 2) {



        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(splash2.getColor());
        batch.draw(
                splash2,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash2.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash2.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
                splash2.getRegionWidth(),
                splash2.getRegionHeight());
        batch.end();
    }
    if(score == 3) {

        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(splash3.getColor());
        batch.draw(
                splash3,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash3.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash3.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
                splash3.getRegionWidth(),
                splash3.getRegionHeight());
        batch.end();

    }

    if(score == 4) {

        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(splash4.getColor());
        batch.draw(
                splash4,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash4.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash4.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
                splash4.getRegionWidth(),
                splash4.getRegionHeight()
        );
        batch.end();

    }

    if(score >= 5) {

        batch.begin();
        batch.setColor(splash5.getColor());
        batch.draw(
                splash5,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash5.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash5.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
                splash5.getRegionWidth(),
                splash5.getRegionHeight()

        );
        batch.end();


    }




    Globals.game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width, height);
    viewport.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    splash.getTexture().dispose();
    splash2.getTexture().dispose();
    splash3.getTexture().dispose();
    splash4.getTexture().dispose();
    splash5.getTexture().dispose();
    hud.dispose();
}


}
```

Okay so this is the whole class. 
I can't understand why the Sprite doesn't change when score does.

Comment: may be you forgot this line `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` in your render method!!

Comment: There is no reason there should be two SpriteBatches.

Comment: You are also missing a `batch.begin();` in the first `if` block.

Comment: I've corrected that, but the problem is still the same. Any ideas? I have also added the whole class so you can easily see what's wrong because I can't figure it out :)

Comment: Dont use `batch.draw(sprite...);` but `sprite.draw(batch);` instead, it saves you a lot of code. Also don't use boxing (use `int` instead of `Integer`). You can also move the calls to `batch.begin();` and `batch.end();` out of branches, so you get `batch.begin(); if (score < 2) splash.draw(batch); if (score < 3) splash2.draw(batch); /*etc.*/ batch.end();`. Also you are using the texture coordinates for world coordinates and are using banana units, don't do that, see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems. Also see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer

Comment: I don't fully understand how I can change the texture coordinates, so it fits my class. Can you give an example how I could have it instead? Thanks btw! :)